# MVC datetime parameter for Controller & View

Tags: model-view-controller, viewmodel

I was wondering if anyone can help I'm very new to MVC and after following some videos on MVA I'm trying to create my own new view and controller based on an existing model.  I seem to be getting stuck trying to display the search results on the view.  (I'll adjust the linq query at a later stage)

So my Model is:

```
[Key]
    public int BookingID { get; set; }
    public int RoomID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Arrival_Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime Departure_Date { get; set; }
```

I have added a new action result in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Availability(DateTime? StartDate)
    {
        ViewBag.StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);

        var GetBookings = from m in db.Bookings
                          where m.Arrival_Date.Date <= (StartDate)
                          select m;

        if (!StartDate.HasValue)
        {
            GetBookings = db.Bookings.Where(x => x.Arrival_Date <= StartDate);
        }

        return View(GetBookings);

    }
```

And finally added a view named Availability pointing to the model with an input:

```
@model IEnumerable<SuiteUI.Models.Booking>
```

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

```
    <input type="datetime" value="@(ViewBag.StartDate)" />
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-default" />
</p>
```

}

```
 <p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
```

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoomID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Arrival_Date)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Departure_Date)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Arrival_Date)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Departure_Date)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.BookingID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.BookingID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.BookingID })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Hopefully this isn't too bad so far, I think I am missing a POST action to handle displaying the results but this is where I'm stuck, any ideas or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sorted, by removing the parameter from the GET request, and adding a POST Actionresult with the parameter this is now working

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Availability()
    {
        ViewBag.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        return View(db.Bookings.ToList());

    }

[HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Availability(DateTime? StartDate)
     {

         var GetBookings = from m in db.Bookings
                           where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.Arrival_Date) <= (StartDate)
                           select m;

         if (!StartDate.HasValue)
         {
             GetBookings = db.Bookings.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Arrival_Date) <= StartDate);
         }

         return View(GetBookings);

     }
```